# TeamCity: Build only when changes are available

Tags: build.gradle, teamcity-9.0

I have the following structure in my TeamCity

```
Commons
 * Commons Release Build (takes quite long because of integration tests)
Applications
 * AppA Release Build
 * AppB Release Build
 * AppC Release Build
```

All three (independent) Applications depends on the Commons-Release-Build. Currently, the single Applications trigger the Commons-Release-Build before building. But in most cases the Commons-Release-Build hasn't changed, so it is unnecessary to rebuild it.

Is it somehow possible to configure Teamcity so it triggers the commons-release-build only when changes are available?
Or is it possible to tell the commons-release-build to do nothing when no changes are available?

NOTE: Gradle is used for every build.

Thanks in advance
Guenther

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer to my own question:
It is possible to trigger the commons-build, and say "only build when changes are available", but the better solution is to configure the commons-library not to build at all but to be triggered by the depending projects when changes are detected. So do

- Disable VCS-Triggers in commons
- Create VCS-Triggers in the depending projects

  - enable the Flag "Trigger a build on changes in snapshot dependencies" on all the VCS-Triggers of the depending projects

Comment: @smec-guenter: please consider **edit** your answer and provide the *full* solution, since the link you shared can not be accessed without an account.